# How to add secondary icon pack incase primary icon pack doesn't have icons?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes

As the question says, I like one icon pack but it doesn't have icons for some actions so it doesn't work properly in some applications. The following image shows the toolbar of GParted. And as you can see most of the icons are just squares. When I set icon pack to Yaru in tweaks it works properly but not in some themes. I want to configure icons such that use icons from the icon pack but if not found an appropriate icon then use it from yaru.

[image]

My second hunch is that this is happening because all the icons in yaru are png but the icons in the custom icon pack are SVG. Is this a reason why it is not displayed?

I tried adding Yaru to inherit field in icon pack theme file but it didn't work. Right now I am stuck with broken icons in some places. Let me know if there is some solution to it.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear for me what you are trying to achieve but might be helpful the output of `dpkg -l | grep icon-theme`. You can try installing `gnome-icon-theme hicolor-icon-theme adwaita-icon-theme-full` packages

Comment: @PabloBianchi I know about icon themes and how to add icons. What I want to know is how to merge two icon packs. If one icon pack doesn't have assets then I want to set a secondary icon pack.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Install the gnome tweaks pkg.

> sudo apt install gnome-tweaks

Open it, go to the appearance menu, then Icons, try to change for someone in the dropdown menu.

If you want add new icons, just download them and move the folder to /usr/share/icons folder, reopen Gnome Tweaks and choose it.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I know about icon themes and how to add icons. What I want to know is how to merge two icon packs. If one icon pack doesn't have assets then I want to set a secondary icon pack.